# Nested SQL Generator?

Tags: java, sql

I am trying to create a nested SELECT SQL statment. I store all value and id and want to select rows that satisfy multiple values. How can I generate a SELECT statement using Java? For example,

```
ID VALUE
1  RED
2  BIG
1  SMALL
1  SMOOTH
2  TALL
```

.....

To select an item that is both red and small the statement would be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE table.value = RED AND 
       id IN (SELECT * 
              FROM table 
              WHERE table.value = SMALL AND id IN (...))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of problem is called `Relational Division`

```
SELECT ID
FROM tableName
WHERE VALUE IN ('SMALL','SMOOTH')
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/42cff/3)

the query above will result `1` since the ID contains **both** records.

If no unique constraint was enforce on `value` for every `ID`, `DISTINCT` is required.

```
SELECT ID
FROM tableName
WHERE VALUE IN ('SMALL','SMOOTH')
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT VALUE) = 2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/42cff/5)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*with duplicate*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fbd22/1)

OTHER(s)

- [SQL of Relational Division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

Comment: Thank you. This works fine if there is only one VALUE column. What if I want one more column called VALUE 2 to be added?

Answer (score 0):

```
select ID
from MyTable
where VALUE in ('RED', 'SMALL')
group by ID
having count(distinct VALUE) = 2
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9b05e/1)

**Results**:

```
| ID |
------
|  1 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general way to approach this:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having max(case when value = 'Red' then 1 else 0 end) = 1 and
       max(case when value = 'Small' then 1 else 0 end) = 1
```

In other words, membership in the set becomes a clause in the `having` statement.  These can be both inclusion and exclusion (use `= 0` instead of `= 1`) and optional (use `or` instead of `and`).